# Contenido del grid en css no me ocupa toda la ventana

Tags: html, css, imagen, grid, gallery

Quiero que la galería me ocupe todo el ancho de la ventana. Pero como se ve en la imagen solo ocupa la mitad. Sigo los mismos pasos que en el tutorial, pero a el del video si se esparcen las imágenes por toda la ventana, esto lo arrglo normalmente con un width de 100vh en el body, pero con grid no me sirve.
[image: imagen del problema]

Intente con este código pero igual no sirve: (También intente darle al body un width:100vh y tampoco)

```css
body{
    background: radial-gradient(circle,#fff,#bbb);
    padding: 15px;
}
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    width: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(200px,1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
    gap:10px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
} 
img:first-child{
    grid-column: 1/span 3;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}
img:nth-child(6){
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 3/5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2baa56dd35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Grid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP._1utn4QJ3DInQNhiSr0CMwHaFj?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.dIfW9a_5bF24GYBaAoTd0wAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.LkA65KEAFQFu8U65z5I2dgHaEK?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.2Az6DXdh6prU9aPebm7QnwAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.URldIXhkARYGvf7a6WjVAAHaFj?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.qDqfagTnIEaPy-eRmKVlFAAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.qROsrrqBTFVIbFL1652LIQHaEK?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.A5Mph48aSJhi3y2wx_DhhQHaEK?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a6e6f209858a40759e829ff4d6e88815?rik=N5kLSwztV%2bVhLA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwallpaperswide.com%2fdownload%2fspatial_fantasy-wallpaper-480x272.jpg&ehk=QSq7%2b45UXLSWEfB3wg09idgikeDugeuQ0N3Z2hs2hM8%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.I9dc8U-0Ahbji53kVS_aCgHaEo?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.uaHGbyyskHVjiOQCrkp1TgHaEo?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.f19eeb1f6a6b292ece224f0e5c14f771?rik=qKumSnRbQ9sJ3Q&riu=http%3a%2f%2f4.bp.blogspot.com%2f-wXAyGZXX33o%2fTkYWZdn3rqI%2fAAAAAAAAC-s%2fRvQwn88i6Mk%2fs1600%2fCool%2bHD%2bWallpapers%2bs.jpg&ehk=4WllFBezOdjdYjhGmDMqp4PscvkewhyPmHx4PMR%2fz9M%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-J3HBc-glZJ8/TiK1DwtO4jI/AAAAAAAABOg/R8UuiQb4WMU/s1600/hd+wallpapers+widescreen3.jpg">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.d3b957568f4c190910b41d9165606613?rik=8NVYOpfsBHdo7w&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwallpapercave.com%2fwp%2fl6rxuuH.jpg&ehk=aUoX274r8QekyhP36RUpb3GHKXtOQEsxfzFWFcTAzwQ%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.977641522c18088b9c9e53773e763131?rik=9TL3xt0BBMNPRA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.d955f413a7e9527fbee0aff9a4eb8c27?rik=8RJDxPjmaujckA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwallpapercave.com%2fwp%2fUNGAb7u.jpg&ehk=cIBePKJnPRfSksGCW1SsLmcXDm4JXHB7r20E7FX6Vks%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.be9809c7849ea074c9d892947349fee7?rik=MSkr6yA5Wv9crQ&riu=http%3a%2f%2fimages3.alphacoders.com%2f578%2f5785.jpg&ehk=24a4RUZ5TzlRL%2b38leUwD%2fjJi7tdy4SyATlFbHQxIVE%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
        <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-o8Dytdqf5zk/Tg__t-AK7mI/AAAAAAAAAQQ/pv1E_kftrE4/s1600/Cool+Wallpapers+%25288%2529.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simplemente elimina el `width: 100vh` y en todo caso `vh` responde el `heigth` del viewport, y lo que tu quieres es el ancho es decir `100vw` (con "w" final de width), que en tu caso no va a funcionar correctamente porque tienes padding en el body.

Comment: Si solo era cambiarlo a "vw", muchas gracias